# Help with a random walk problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $\xi_1,\xi_2,...$ be a sequence of random variables such that $\xi_i=-1$ or $\xi_i=1$ for $i=1,2,...$. Let $x(n)$ be the position of a random walk at time $n$, i.e. $x(n)=\xi_1+\xi_2+...+\xi_n$. The random walk satisfies that if $x(n)=x$, then $\Bbb E\xi_{n+1}=\frac{1}{x}$. Show $\Bbb E[x^{2k}(n)]\simeq \frac{n^k(2k+1)}{2^kk!}$ where $\simeq$ denotes equivalent infinity.

I have tried several methods, including induction but none is successful. The book gives the following hint.

[image]

Hope someone can provide some help. Thank you!

Comment: What is $p$ in  $\frac{n^p(2p+1)}{2^pp!}$?

Comment: @NikitaEvseev Sorry. I corrected the typos.

Comment: You might want to elicit some obscure points : 
Any info on the probability of the up and down move for $\xi _i$ ? 
The line on $E[\xi _{n+1}|x(n)=x] = \frac{1}{x}$ is the $x$ a constant ?

Comment: @zebullon The only condition we can use is $E[\xi _{n+1}|x(n)=x] = \frac{1}{x}$ and $x$ is not a constant. It says if $x(n) = x$, then $\Bbb E \xi_{n+1}=1/x$.

Comment: Calculate $E(x^{2k}_{n+1}-x^{2k}_n)=\Delta_{n+1}$, use $E(x^{2k}_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta_n$ and approximate sum with an integral.

Comment: @A.S. I am having trouble in calculating $\Delta_{n+1}$.

Comment: @A.S. For exaxmple. $\Bbb E [{x^4}(n + 1) - {x^4}(n)] = \Bbb E[C_4^3 x^3(n)e +C_4^2 x^2(n)e^2 + C_4^1x(n)e^3+e^4]=\Bbb E[C_4^3 x^2(n)+C_4^2 + C_4^1 \frac{1}{x^2(n)} + e^4]$ where $e$ is the $n+1$ step of the random walk and $C_4^3$ denotes "4 chooes 3". I don't know how to get rid of $x(n)$...

Comment: @Tony $E(e^{2k})=E(1)=1$  and $E(e^{2k+1})=E(e)$ which tells you (keeping the higest power of $x$ only) $\Delta_{n+1}\approx (\binom {2k} 1+\binom {2k} {2})E(x^{2k-2}_n)$. Now use your inductive hypothesis for $E(x^{2k-2})$ and integrate.

Comment: The random walk has a memory, since $p(\xi_{n+1}=+1|\,X(n)=x)=\frac12(1-\frac1x)$. But I don't understand how $p(\xi_1=+1)$ is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by definition $p(\xi_1=+1)=1$, such that $\mathbb E_1$ is the average with this initial value. For larger values of $n$, we have by hypothesis
$$p(\xi_{n+1}=+1\;|\;\mathbf x(n)=x)=\frac12\left(1+\frac1x\right).$$
This is valid only if $\mathbf x(n)>0$, but it is easy to show by induction that it is always the case (because when $\mathbf x(n)=1$ the next step is necessarily $+1$, so $\mathbf x(n+1)=2$).

Let us use the hint
$$\mathbb E_1\left[ \mathbf x^{2k}(n+1)-\mathbf x^{2k}(n)\right]=
\sum_{p=0}^{2k-1}\binom{2k}p \mathbb E_1\left[\mathbf x^{2k-p}(n)\right]\;\mathbb E_1\left[\xi_{n+1}^p\;|\;\mathbf x(n)\right]. $$
If $p$ is even, then $\xi_{n+1}^p=1.$ If $p$ is odd, then $\mathbb E_1\left[\mathbf x^{2k-p}(n)\xi_{n+1}^p\;|\;\mathbf x(n)=x\right]=\mathbb E_1\left[\mathbf x^{2k-p}(n)\xi_{n+1}\;|\;\mathbf x(n)=x\right]=\frac1x\mathbb E_1\left[\mathbf x^{2k-p}(n)\;|\;\mathbf x(n)=x\right]=x^{2k-p-1}$.
As a conclusion, we get
$$\mathbb E_1\left[ \mathbf x^{2k}(n+1)-\mathbf x^{2k}(n)\right]=
\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}\left(\binom{2k}{2p}+\binom{2k}{2p+1}\right)\mathbb E_1[\mathbf x^{2k-2p}(n)]=\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}\binom{2k+1}{2p+1}\mathbb E_1[\mathbf x^{2k-2p}(n)].$$
Therefore 
$$\mathbb E_1\left[\mathbf x^{2k}(n)\right]=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}
\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}\binom{2k+1}{2p+1}\mathbb E_1[\mathbf x^{2k-2p}(j)].$$
 You can easily verify the induction
hypothesis $\mathbb E_1[\mathbf x^{2k}(n)]\simeq \frac{(2k+1)n^k}{2^kk!}$.